# onchange function ajax call not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've created a form where a `select_tag` contains an `onchange` function:

form (**advertisments/_form.html.erb**):

```
<div class="controls advertise-medium-select">
   <%= select_tag 'advertisment[medium_id]', options_for_select(@mediums.collect { |mid| [mid.name, mid.id] }), :prompt => 'Select Media', onchange: 'get_media_categories()' %>
</div>
```

In my **advertisments.js** file:  here, console log always prints the `medium` if I change the `select_tag` option, but not going to the `fetch_media_categories` method.

```
function get_media_categories(){
    var medium = $('#advertisment_medium_id option:selected').val();
    console.log(medium);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/advertisments/fetch_media_categories',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {medium_id: medium}
    })
}
```

my **routes** file:

```
resources :advertisments do
    collection do
      get :fetch_media_categories, :fetch_media_pages
    end
  end
```

and **application.js** file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.easing.1.3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery.fancybox.pack
//= require jquery.fancybox-media
//= require prettify
//= require jquery.quicksand
//= require setting
//= require jquery.flexslider
//= require animate
//= require custom
//= require pricing_custom
//= require advertisments
//= require_tree .
```

Currently, the onchange function working on chrome, but not in firefox(version 39.0). Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in advertisment.js

```
 $(function () {

  $('#advertisment_medium_id').on('change', function() {
      var medium = $('#advertisment_medium_id option:selected').val();
      console.log(medium);
      $.ajax({
          url: '/advertisments/fetch_media_categories',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {medium_id: medium}
      });
  });

});
```

Comment: No, there is no error. I don't know why, but I've moved the controller ajax requesting actions to a different controller, and it worked!